# Custom values not being read from externalized properties file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application whose **application.properties** looks like what's given below: -

```
server.port=5000
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql:.......
spring.datasource.username = .......
spring.datasource.password = ......
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy


logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.path=/var/log/


controller.condition.otp = true
.........
.........
```

I also have a controller called **OTP** that is enabled or disabled based on the value of the custom variable `controller.condition.otp` in the config file and on the controller class I have the following condition given

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "controller", name = "condition.otp", havingValue = "true")
@RestController
public class OTP {
........
........
}
```

When the file (application.properties) resides in the resource folder, the custom config variable is read and the controller works just fine. However, when the same file is moved to a different location and read from there, the custom config variable is ignored / not read and I get a **404** when I hit the controller's path ( `/otp/generate` ).

Following is how I'm reading the config file from a different location

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/.local/application.properties")
public class PropertyConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide externalized property location in `spring.config.location` environment property.

`@PropertySource` will not work in this case. Issue is logged in Jira https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8539

Comment: read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-the-location-of-external-properties you have to define an environment property, but I see that @Sachin was faster :)